# how to check logged in user in context processors file in django

Tags: python, django

I am using context processors for showing total products in cart and other details in my project's header and footer.
This is my file for context processors file "custom_context.py"

```
from models import Event, Ticket_Cart_details

def get_base_content(request):
    music_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='music', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    sports_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='sports', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    experience_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='experience', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    lifestyle_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='lifestyle', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
```

The above code does not contain any information about logged in user now i have to write a code in which i have to get data of logged in user.

```
from models import Event, Ticket_Cart_details

def get_base_content(request):
    music_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='music', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    sports_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='sports', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    experience_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='experience', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    lifestyle_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='lifestyle', status = True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        current_cart_products = Ticket_Cart_details.objects.all().filter(user_id=request.user.id, session_id=request.session.session_key)
    current_cart_products = Ticket_Cart_details.objects.all().filter(session_id=request.session.session_key)
```

In the above code "request" will not work, so how can i get records of logged in user using this

Comment: What do you mean by 'request will not work'?

Comment: In this context processor request.user.is_authenticated() is not working

Comment: Did you make sure your context_processor is after the request context processor? (django.template.context_processors.request)

Comment: in settings.py file ?

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok. You should be able to use `request.user.is_authenticated()` in a context processor without problems. What do you mean 'request.user.is_authenticated() is not working'? If it gives an error, then what is the error. If it returns `False`, then that suggests that the user is not logged in.

Comment: @Alasdair I have also checked it after user login, event using " if request.COOKIES['my_cart_cookie_session_id']: " and my_cart_cookie_session_id variable has data in it, but still its not satisfying if condition

Comment: As I said before, I can't tell what the problem is from the code you've shown. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: ok thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I getting the same problem. When a non allowed_host try access my application, I can't get request.user info. I got: `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`. My context_processors is after request context processors.

Answer (score 1):

You are using request well, but when you work with context processors, you have to return all the data that you want. For example:

```
def get_base_content(request):
    music_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='music', status=True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    sports_events = Event.objects.all().filter(category='sports', status=True).values('id','event_title').order_by('-id')[:4]
    return {"music_events": music_events,
            "sports_events": sports_events ,
            }
```

Additionally, for the problems with user not allowed or not logged in, you have to handle it with a anonymous data or something like this.

```
def get_base_content(request):
    if not request.user:
        music_events = 'none'
        sports_events = 'none'
```